# Fatal error: Uncaught Hybridauth\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A valid callback url is required. in

Tags: php, login

Estoy intentando crear un login en mi página web mediante las redes sociales pero en el momento en que intento loguearme con twitter, me sale este error:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Hybridauth\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A valid callback url is required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php:312 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Adapter\OAuth1.php(163): Hybridauth\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->setCallback(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php(109): Hybridauth\Adapter\OAuth1->configure() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Hybridauth.php(141): Hybridauth\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->__construct(Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Hybridauth.php(101): Hybridauth\Hybridauth->getAdapter('Twitter') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\App\Auth\Auth.php(33): Hybridauth\Hybridauth->authenticate('Twitter') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\indexRedesSociales.php(29): Auth::getUserAuth() #6 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\RedesSociales\vendor\hybridauth\hybridauth\src\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php on line 312**

Interpreto que podría haber puesto un callback inválido...este es el Callback URI / Redirect URL que he puesto en mi aplicación de twitter: http://localhost/RedesSociales/prueba.php

Mi fichero Auth.php es este:

`<?php

use Hybridauth\Hybridauth;

class Auth
{
protected static $allow = ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Google'];

```
protected static function issetRequest()
{
  if(isset($_GET['login'])){
    if(in_array($_GET['login'], self::$allow)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

public static function getUserAuth()
{
  if(self::issetRequest())
  {
    $service = $_GET['login'];

    $hybridAuth = new Hybridauth(__DIR__ . '\config.php');

    $adapter = $hybridAuth->authenticate($service);

    $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

    self::storeUser($service, $userProfile);

    //redirect user
    header('Location: indexRedesSociales.php');
  }
}
```

}

?>`

Comment: El host no debería ser `localhost`, porque la llamada -de retorno- la ejecuta el servidor de tweeter y seguramente en su servidor no existe la ruta `RedesSociales/prueba.php`. El host debe ser accesible desde internet.

Comment: Gracias. Pero entonces no puedo probar el código desde un localhost? Me gustaría probarlo 'offline' ya que no tengo todavía ninguna página web en internet.

Comment: Hay opciones, pero primero necesitarías una respuesta -de tweeter- de ejemplo para probar tu implementación del callback/webhook. Usar un hosting gratuito siempre es opción.